# How can I quickly earn gems in Super Bomberman R?

Tags: super-bomberman-r

In Super Bomberman R, only 8 of the game’s 30 multiplayer stages are unlocked by default. The other 22 stages must be purchased for 2,500-4,000 gems each.

A standard multiplayer match earns around 150 gems, meaning it could take weeks of regular play to unlock every stage.

Is there a faster way to earn gems in Super Bomberman R?